# Why showing votes and comments in reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Don't you think positive/negative votes and comments to questions can influence reviewers?

[image]

In this case, for example, one can be discouraged to read all the question, knowing that it already received 2 downvotes.

Reviews could be more more neutral and subjective without other people votes/comments.

Comment: If it's under review... **somebody didn't like it** by definition. Why shouldn't you review it in that light? You're reviewing both the question AND the flag at that point.

Comment: @Paulie_D Many of the queues are fed, at least in part, by automated mechanisms, so it may well not be the case that an actual person looked at the post and thought that it merited being in that review queue.

Comment: @Servy ...perhaps I should have said *sombody or something*.

Answer (score 12):

Of course they can influence reviews.  We *want* them to be influencing reviews.  If a given post has a lot of downvotes and comments explaining why it's off topic, that's useful information for a close vote reviewer to help them realize that the question is off topic and that it should be closed accordingly.

For the types of queues that show this information (some, such as the suggested edit review queue do not, because this information wouldn't be relevant to whether the edit is appropriate), the information is potentially going to be pointing out or indicating action(s) that the reviewer should take.  This is great, it improves the odds that they notice that they should take that action and, even if they would have realized it eventually without it, it helps them review quicker and more accurately.

Comment: Another example of comments influencing reviews: The code in an asker's comment can define the difference between sending a question from [Triage](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats) to [H&I](//stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats) or [Close Votes](//stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats).

Answer (score 2):

Not showing comments would also waste time of reviewers who also want to help OP - if you don't see comment already suggesting action to OP you may want to write one yourself. It will waste time and also create needless duplication in comments.

It will also hide useful information like "this already discussed in xxxxx" (instead of VTC/flag) - reviewer may simply close question instead of letting others spent other's time reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are useful information for reviewers, and we need those to make informed decisions in the review queues.

For instance, a question in triage / CV queues may be salvageable by a targeted edit if the OP has left a comment that baked into the question would make it on topic. This happens quite a few times. Not showing those would mean a disservice to the OPs and the reviewers.

Votes are also important. If I come across a question that's at -10 with 5 comments explaining how it's off topic, then thats usually a good idea that a gut feeling that it's off topic is right.

All in all the review queues aim to provide you with the information to make the best possible informed decision on a post - and they do that, which is why what exactly is shown is hand-tailored to every queue.